# How to purge SDDM/Plasma completely

Tags: kde, lightdm, sddm

I recently installed KDE just to give it a go. I didn't really like it, so ran `sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop plasma-desktop`. That seemed to fix it initially, after two reboots everything was back to Ubuntu and using lightdm as the login manager.

However, it has since started this ***very*** annoying habit of using `sddm` as the login manager. This then messes up all sorts of stuff, including sound and TTYs 1-6.

So, I figured I would run `sudo apt-get purge sddm` and be done with it. Wrong, I get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge sddm
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  sddm*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 1164703 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing sddm (0.11.0-0ubuntu10) ...
Purging configuration files for sddm (0.11.0-0ubuntu10) ...
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: script virtualbox: service virtualbox already provided!
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/sddm/authority’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package sddm (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sddm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also, I get these random graphical glitches all the time, with a constant set of these guys at random spots on my screen:

[image]

The glitches and audio issues only happen with sddm is the login manager. When lightdm is the login manager everything works just fine.

Is there any way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: The `apt-get purge sddm` seems to fail because it wants to remove a file which isn't there, so I'd just create it and try to purge the package again: `sudo touch /var/run/sddm/authority ; sudo apt-get purge sddm` maybe it's safer to do that without any active graphical sessions, meaning you log in through a TTY only.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up resolving this as far as I can tell by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and selecting `lightdm` instead of `sddm` and rebooting.

Then, from the login screen I was able to enter TTY1 via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and run `sudo dpkg -R sddm`.

This seemed to work, as `sddm` is no longer an option under `dpkg-reconfigure lighdm` and I've had no issues since with the audio or graphical glitches.